# Within express routes, why have `./routes` instead of `/routes`?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Almost every example I have seen, the app.js is using `require` with the path `./`. I am wondering why can't we just use `/`. So for example, why can't we do the following.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var routes = require('/routes');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `require('/routes');`, but that would look for the `routes` file at the top level of your disk volume (in the root directory).  So, if the current volume is `//mydisk`, then `require('/routes');` would look for the file at `//mydisk/routes`.

The reason people use `require('./routes')` is to load the `routes` files from the current directory, not from the top level of the current volume.

Answer (score 0):

Because of Unix/Linux paths. In Linux / Mac, `/routes` means that you trying to find file/dir. `routes` in Root directory of your System.

`./routes` - is a relative path, that means you trying to find file/dir. routes relative from current file.

Comment: Thank you for that.